# name an object in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, promise

I'm doing multiple fetchs with `Promise.all`. So I receive data like this :

```
[
   0: {
      ...
   },
   1: {
      ...
   }
]
```

But I would like to name my Objects. So I can do `data.myObject` istead of `data[0]`.

I would like the index to be a string that I chose.
For example, i'd like to get :

```
[
   "home": {
      ...
   },
   "product": {
      ...
   }
]
```

Is is possible ? Thanks

Comment: your question is definitely unclear, can you please provide what you've tried to do also please explain what the new index would be if it isn't `0-1-2-3...`

Comment: Where do the names come from? How do you map each item in the array to a name?

Comment: @JoeClay it can be the id inside the object, or I can just set it myself as a string

Comment: Structuring your data as an object with named properties is only useful if your code knows the property names already.  Also you might lose the order of the elements.

Comment: If using bluebird.js you could take a look at the [`.props`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.props.html) or [`.join`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.join.html) apis.

Comment: This is an object literal: `{ key: "string", key: 3 }`, This is an array: `["string", 3]` Arrays do not have visible "names" (keys). They do have index numbers which is the closest you'll get to as far as a "name" goes for arrays.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like you want to convert Array to an object so you can get data by calling a key.

```js
const arr = [ { id: "home", val: "val1" }, { id: "product", val: "val2" }];
const convert = arr.reduce((a,b) => (a[b.id] ??= b,a),{});
console.log(convert);
console.log(convert.home);
```

Comment: Clear as water. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. `Promise.all` works on iterables (like arrays), not on objects. Name your values *after* the `Promise.all` call:

```
const data = await Promise.all([…, …]);
const home = data[0], product = data[1];
```

becomes with destructuring

```
const [home, product] = await Promise.all([…, …]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.all` works with an array. Arrays deal in numerically indexed (ordered) values.

You'd need to have a name stored *somewhere* for each promise, and then generate the object from them once the promises had resolved.

e.g.

```
const names = ['home', 'product'];
const promises = [fetchHome(), fetchProduct()];
const results = await Promise.all(promises);
const resultsByName = names.reduce((prev, curr, index) => {
    return {...prev, [curr]: results[index]};
}, {});
```

You could use a similar approach without the second array if the name was available in the resolved values of `fetchHome()` and `fetchProduct()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can destructure the array of Promise results in the Promise.all.

```js
const [home, product, toolbar, nav] = await Promise.all([
getHome(), getProduct(), getToolBar(), getNav()
]);
```

Since the results are an array like anything else you can destructure arrays and even use the ...rest syntax:

```js
const [home, product, toolbar, nav, ...otherPromises] = await Promise.all([
getHome(), getProduct(), getToolBar(), getNav(), getOtherThing1()
]);
// otherPromises will be an array that you'll have to access
// with numeric keys as before:
// eg. otherPromises[0] might be the first non-named promise
// the result of getOtherThing1()
```